# Keeping the meshes "thickness" the same when scaling an object

Tags: xna, c#, algorithm

I've been bashing my head for the past couple of weeks trying to find a way to help me accomplish, on first look very easy task. So, I got this one object currently made out of 5 cuboids (2 **sides**, 1 **top**, 1 **bottom**, 1 **back**), this is just for an example, later on there will be whole range of different set ups. Now, the thing is when the user chooses to scale the whole object this is what should happen:

**X** scale: **top** and **bottom** cuboids should get scaled by a scale factor, **sides** should get moved so they are positioned just like they were before(in this case at both ends of **top** and **bottom** cuboids), **back** should get scaled so it fits like before(if I simply scale it by a scale factor it will leave gaps  on each side).

**Y** scale: **sides** should get scaled by a scale factor, **top** and **bottom** cuboid should get moved, and **back** should also get scaled.

**Z** scale: **sides**, **top** and **bottom** cuboids should get scaled, **back** should get moved.

Hope you can help,

---

**EDIT**
I am asking you, if any of you have any idea on how to accomplish this scaling.

I have tried whole bunch of things, from scaling all of the object by the same scale factor, to subtracting and adding sizes to get the right size. But nothing I tried worked, if one mesh got scaled correctly then others didn't.

[Donwload the example object](http://www.2shared.com/file/UrOZ5AZT/test.html).

Comment: Are you wanting the thickness of the "walls" to remain the same?

Comment: Yes thats right, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Your update is pushing your question into the "too localized" realm. It sounds like you're no longer looking for algorithms, but you want code. That's something you'll be unlikely to get.

Comment: I am just looking for a way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm sure you are. I've presented that below. It doesn't mean someone is going to write code for you. If you're still unclear about something in my answer, ask about it.

Comment: You have written it very detailed and very well explained, but I just dont see how this could be used to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps you need to work on explaining what it is you want to do. Not with your source code. Draw pictures, show two different sizes. Something more than what you've got so we can understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

- Apply a [scale matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29) to all the vertices that make up all the objects used to create your form. This is a common procedure, I'm sure XNA has something built in for this. This should be your preferred approach. It's the most common and it will produce the results you want. Additionally, it will work for any combination of shapes you make.
- Scale an invisible box and resize/move your objects to fit around it. Just have six positions that represent each face of a invisible cube. Move those along the axis they represent (top/bottom = y axis, left/right = x axis, front/back = z axis), and have your cuboids make their size and positions match up to the positions. This method would be useful if you wanted to maintain the thickness of your "walls" even after scaling.

  - For example, the top cuboid would use the `top` position as it's position. It would then use each of the side positions to set its width and height.

**EDIT** to clarify the second option.

You have 6 positions:

[image]

Those positions define the positions and size of the shapes you have attached.

For example, the top cuboid would defined as such:

```
position = YP
width = XP-XM
height = wallThickness
depth = ZP-ZM
```

Or the back cuboid would be defined as:

```
position = ZP
width = XP-XM
height = YP-YM
depth = wallThickness
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not really sure what you meant?

Comment: I could explain the whole thing again, or you can tell me what you're unsure about.

Comment: How you meant the second thing, with the invisible box thingie

Comment: First imagine that the right cuboid position is XP, left position = XM, top = YP and so on. You can imagine that re-sizing this box will move the cuboids around, but they'll have gaps. The next step is to just re-size the cuboids to fill the gaps.

Comment: Thats what I am looking for an algorith that would calculate the scale for each mesh.

Comment: Looks like I understood you the first time. The second method I've described above will do what you want. Just think about the back cuboid. If it's center is at ZP, you would set its width to XP-XM and you would set its height to YP-YM and you would keep its depth the same. That would create a cuboid that doesn't have any gaps and has the same thickness no matter its size.

Comment: Yes I would do that if I'd want everything to resize to that exact dimensions, but I want something along these lines. Lets say the whole objects width is 1000 and **backs** width is 964, then if I would scale the whole objects width to 2000, **backs** width should become 1964. Meaning it would keep its diffrence in width(36).

Comment: Now you're wondering, I could just add that diffrence(2000-1000) to **backs** width, yes but that would leed to another problem. Lets say that instead of one complete cuboid, **back** is divided into two cuboids placed next to each other. And lets say that whole objects width is 1000, and those new **backs** width is 500 each. And I scale the whole objects width to 2000(2000-1000), I would get 1000, so adding 500+1000 would leed me to 1500, and 2x1500 means 3000 total width of the **back** side, which is not correct because it should only be 2000. Complicated...

Comment: OK, you can modify the above algorithm to allow for that. You need to implement something like a scene graph. Where there are parent objects and child objects. The child positions are defined in relation to the parent size/position. For example, you could place the two back cuboids at 25% and 75% of their parent's width. That would adjust them to remain in their relative positions when the parent is re-sized. This is similar to the way 2D GUIs are defined. Where moving the parent around and re-sizing it keeps the elements (buttons, menus, etc.) in their correct positions.

Comment: I already have parent child thing implemented. But doesnt what you said only means that child objects would stay in the same positions, I mean I didnt see you mentioning anything about scaling child objects? Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Scaling would be relative to the parent object. Which is what you want. Same as placement.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but the reason why I asked this question was because I was looking for an algorith that would allow me to calculate these things.

Comment: Hey, could you give me a short example of what you said above. How to position objects, I understand the concept, but I have a problem with realizing this.